# Помогите разобраться с ошибками

Tags: c++

Ошибки

> -Error    4   error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals   C:\My Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\lab2\Debug\lab2.exe 1   1   lab2
>
> -Error    3   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl solve(int,int,double *,double * const,int * const)"
>   (?solve@@YAHHHPANQANQAH@Z)    C:\My Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\lab2\lab2\main.obj  lab2
>
> -Error    1   error LNK2005: "int __cdecl decomp(int,int,double *,double *,int * const,int *)" (?decomp@@YAHHHPAN0QAHPAH@Z) already defined in decomp.obj C:\My Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\lab2\lab2\main.obj  lab2
>
> -Error    2   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl solve(int,int,double *,double * const,int * const)"
>   (?solve@@YAHHHPANQANQAH@Z) referenced in function "int __cdecl
>   decomp(int,int,double *,double *,int * const,int *)"
>   (?decomp@@YAHHHPAN0QAHPAH@Z)  C:\My Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\lab2\lab2\decomp.obj    lab2

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "decomp.cpp"
int main()
{

#define NELEMS(x)  (sizeof(x) / sizeof(x[0]))
    double a[] = { 1, 2, 2, 2, 1 };
    double b[] = { 1, 2, 1, 2, 1 };
    double g[] = { 2, 1, 2, 1, 1 };

    //#define  DECOMP_C    101
#define mdim 5
#define INDX(i, j)  (i) * mdim + (j)
    double cond;
    double sum;
    double sum2;
    double det;
    int N = NELEMS(a);
    int flag, pivot[mdim];
    double z[mdim], temp[mdim];
    static double Q[mdim*mdim];

    /*double **Q = (double **)malloc(N*sizeof(double *));
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    Q[i] = (double *)malloc(N*sizeof(double));
    }*/
    int j = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        a[i] = j*j;
        b[i] = j - 1.1999999999;
        g[i] = abs(j - 3);
        j++;
        //printf("%.2f ", a[i]);
    }
    printf("\n%s\n", "Vector a: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        printf("%.2f ", a[i]);

    printf("\n%s\n", "Vector b: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        printf("%.2f ", b[i]);
    printf("\n%s\n", "Vector g: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        printf("%.2f ", g[i]);
    printf("\nLength of array: %d\n", sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]));

    printf("%s\n", "Array Q: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++){
            Q[INDX(i, j)] = a[j] * b[i];
            Q[INDX(j, i)] = a[j] * b[i];
        }


    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
            printf("%8.2f ", Q[INDX(i, j)]);
        printf("\n");
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        sum = 0;
        sum2 = 0;
        //printf("Z[%i]:\n", i);
        for (int k = 0; k < i; k++){
            sum += a[k] * g[k];
            //printf(" |%.2f %.2f| ", a[k], g[k]);

        }
        printf("\n");
        for (int k = i; k < N; k++){
            sum2 += b[k] * g[k];
            //printf(" |%.2f %.2f| ", b[k], g[k]);

        }
        printf("\n");
        z[i] = b[i] * sum + a[i] * sum2;

        //printf("%.2f * %.2f + %.2f * %.2f = %.2f",b[i], sum, a[i], sum2, z[i]);
        //printf("\n");
    }


    printf("%s\n", "Vector Z: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        printf("%.2f ", z[i]);

    printf("\n");
    printf("%s\n", "Try Decomp ");
    decomp(5, mdim, Q, &cond, pivot, &flag);

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
            printf("%8.2f ", Q[INDX(i, j)]);
        printf("\n");
    }

    if (flag == 0)
    {
        printf("%s\n", "Try Solve ");
        solve(5, 5, Q, z, pivot);

        printf("X =  ");
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) printf("%e ", z[i]);
        printf("\n");
        //printf ("Correct answer is [    1.000,    1.000,    1.000, ]\n");

        printf("\n");
        printf("Condition number = %e\n", cond);

        det = pivot[N - 1];
        //printf ("Solution vector\n");
        //for (int i = 0; i < mdim; i++)
        //printf("%f\n", z[i]);
        //printf ("\nDeterminant  = %f\n", det);
    }
    else {
        printf("%s\n", "Flag != 0 ");
        printf("%i\n", flag);
    }
    printf("\n");
    cond = 0;
    printf("x - g\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){
        temp[i] = z[i] - g[i];
        printf("%e\n", temp[i]);
    }

    float max1 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        if (fabs(temp[i]) > fabs(max1)){
            max1 = temp[i];
        }
    printf("||x - g|| = %f\n", max1);
    float max2 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        if (fabs(g[i]) > fabs(max2)){
            max2 = g[i];
        }
    printf("||g|| =  %f\n", max1);
    printf("Result = %f\n", max1 / max2);

}
```

***Спасибо большое!)***

Comment: Во-первых, зачем это вдруг у вас `decomp.cpp` включен в основной файл при помощи `#include`??? Это, очевидно, источник ваших ошибок LNK2005 (двойное определение). А, во-вторых, откуда лезут ошибки LNK2001 (отсутствующее определение) сказать из предоставленной вам информации невозможно. Функция `solve` не определена и куда она девалась - не ясно. Куда???

Comment: Что за тег `decomp` у вопроса?

Comment: Если вы не специалист в C++, никогда не включайте `.cpp` через `#include`. Делайте так, как положено: разделите код на декларацию и имплементацию, поместите декларацию в `.h`, и подключайте только её. Если вы специалист, то вы сами прекрасно знаете, что делаете, и вам советы такого уровня не нужны.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну написано же.

1. Ты вызываешь функцию `solve`, которой нет в исходнике.
2. Функция `decomp` скомпилировалась 2 раза. Как вариант, при наличии такого include'а, можно выставить файлу decomp.cpp do not compile. Хотя по-хорошему, надо подключать h-файл с прототипом вместо cpp с кодом.